# R, keras: TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'shape' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: r, tensorflow, anaconda, keras

I'm trying to make some neural networks in R, using kerasR package on tensorflow within a tensorflow anaconda environment.

Here you can see my setup:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("tensorflow", required = TRUE)

py_config()
```

The result is:

```
python:         C:\Users\Miguel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Miguel/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/python35.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\Miguel\ANACON~1\envs\TENSOR~1
version:        3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017, 21:28:42) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\Miguel\ANACON~1\envs\TENSOR~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.12.1

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\Miguel\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe
 C:\Users\Miguel\ANACON~1\python.exe
```

And this is my code:

```
library(kerasR)
mod <- Sequential()
mod$add(Dense(units = 200, input_shape = 13))
```

Which throws this error message:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'shape' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Detailed traceback: 
  File "c:\users\miguel\documents\github\keras\keras\models.py", line 430, in add layer(x)
  File "c:\users\miguel\documents\github\keras\keras\engine\topology.py", line 558, in __call__ self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "c:\users\miguel\documents\github\keras\keras\layers\core.py", line 827, in build constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "c:\users\miguel\documents\github\keras\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\miguel\documents\github\keras\keras\engine\topology.py", line 391, in add_weight weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "c:\users\miguel\documents\github\keras\keras\initializers.py", line 208, in __call__ dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "c:\users\miguel\documents\github\keras\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", l
```

Unfortunately, I cant`t find suggestions for this R / kerasR / tensrflow / anaconda setup. Your help will be truly appreciated.

My session info:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] kerasR_0.4.1   reticulate_0.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2  Rcpp_0.12.10 knitr_1.15
```

Comment: You need to pass int, not float

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this issue, and attempted some of the hacks suggested in the support thread at https://github.com/statsmaths/kerasR/issues/13 without success.

The solution that worked in the end was abandoning the kerasR library altogether, in favour of [keras](https://rstudio.github.io/keras/) by the RStudio team.

It seems to offer equivalent functionality, with the virtue of actually working; also, given that it appears to have support from the RStudio project, may stand a better chance of staying on top of the ongoing dependency hell that seems inevitable with DL frameworks in Python right now.